# Does Search Engine Robot Reads Image?

Tags: image, seo

I have a programmer that told me better not to use image in website as search engine robot wont read it. I told him that if we apply title to the image, it would work as fine as text. I also proposed that using image will give visual advantage as well. I need to know if there is any SEO expert out there can comment on this as i need to propose a intelligent argument to help my boss to decide.

Answer (score 1):

You and your programmer are both partly right.

- Search engine cannot read images = true.

Search engines can only read/index text.  If you have any "important" information on the page that **must** be indexed, don't put it in an image.  Use text: paragraphs, headings, etc.

- ALT text of images can provide information to search engines = true.

The description text of the images do get read by search engines, and will help.  However, how much information can you really put into this description?  Not much, and this isn't meant for that purpose anyway.

**Conclusion**: Using images is okay.  BUT do not rely on images for any crucial information.  The images should be used to "enhance" the content, rather than replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Time will come and they will implement optical character recognition (OCR) to their robots and then it would maybe possible to read text from images.